# How to constantly update a Text View

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm trying out making an app using Android Studio and I want to constantly update a text view.

I at first thought I should use a loop but that ended up not even running for some reason.

```
        TextView amount = findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        final SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        int p = seekBar.getProgress() + 1;
        amount.setText(String.valueOf(p));
            });
        }
    }
```

With this method it doesn't update the results text view. I would like it to constantly update the text view so it shows what number the seek bar is on.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an event for update the state of SeekBar and TextView, in this case I user a Handler(android.os) for update the views each 100 milliseconds of time, but you can use another event like the load of a web service or another.

In your case, it doesn't update because you just update the state of variable, but never update the state of seekbar, that is the reason it will never increment the current state.

```
private void startLoopUntilEnd() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            progress++;
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
            startLoopUntilEnd();
        }
    };
    if (currentState <seekBar.getMax()){
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
    }
}
```

You can call this method from onCreate in case of Activity or onResume in case of Fragment and after it will go until the SeekBar is complete recursively.
If you want to change the max of seekBar, you can set it in xml or in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      

    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     

    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {     

        amount.setTextprogress);

    }       
});
```